# Firebase fetching ordered by value only 20 first entries

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Forum that will have an unlimited number of topics created by users. So for performance I'd like to fetch only 20 topics or so at a time. When the user goes to the bottom of the Table View we should fetch 20 more and so on.

The problem is I am currently sorting the topics AFTER I fetch all of them from Firebase and I am having a hard time having them ordered correctly directly on Firebase BEFORE I fetch them and that's the only way I can see this working.

The topics are ordered by "last-post" which is a string on Firebase that I convert to Date and reorder after I pull from Firebase.

```
   func fetchTopicsFromFirebase(){

    guard let cat = self.currentCategory else {return}

    DataService.ds.Topics_Base.child(cat.key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {//snapshots = all topics
            self.allTopics = []

            for top in snapshots{

                if let dict = top.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{

                    guard let title = dict["title"] as? String else {continue}
                    guard let text = dict["text"] as? String else {continue}
                    guard let time = dict["time"] as? String else {continue}
                    guard let username = dict["username"] as? String else {continue}

                    let newTopic = Topic(subject: title, text: text, time: time, topicKey: top.key, username: username)

                    if let lastPost = dict["last-post"] as? String{
                    newTopic.lastPostTime = HelperMethods.convertStringToDate(myString: lastPost)
                    }
                    if let email = dict["email"] as? String{
                        let validEmail = HelperMethods.removeSpecialCharactersFromEmail(email: email)
                        DataService.ds.Users_Base.child(validEmail).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
                            if let userDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                                if let imgUrl = userDict["profile_image_url"] as? String{
                                    newTopic.opImageUrl = imgUrl
                                 }
                                self.allTopics.append(newTopic)
                                self.allTopics.sort { $0.lastPostTime! > $1.lastPostTime!}//lastPostTime is a Date object

                                if (self.allTopics.count == snapshots.count){
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }

                }
            }
        }

               }
    )
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's not working? Surely you tried a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), such as `ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "lastpost"). queryLimitedToFirst(21)`? And then used the 21st key in the list with `queryStartingAtValue(lastFetchedKey).queryLimitedToFirst(21)` to grab the next 20?

Comment: Thanks yes I tried that but it still doesn't order properly. I created a new child called timestamp(Integer) and am trying to use that to order but it's not ordering it quite right. child(cat.key).queryOrdered(byChild: "last-post-timestamp").queryLimited(toFirst: 21).observe(.value...

Comment: What does *not ordering it quite right* mean? Did you remove the extra sorting code from your question as if Firebase is delivering sorted data to the app,  you don't need to sort it again. Can you post a snippet of your Firebase structure, as *text* please, no images. That can be obtained from the Firebase console, magical three dots in upper right corner, then export JSON. Copy and paste a small example from that text file.